# How to be sure about All events have 'Sesssion Info' like ga_session_id, ga_session_number IN NEW PROPERTY APP+WEB for GA

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, nosql

i'm try to verify whether All events have 'session info' in new property App+Web using BigQuery.

here is the sample data schema of my table.
[event_params.key got ga_session_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COfAx.png)

than i tried this query.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event_name, COUNT(event_name) as count_event_name
FROM
  `mytable`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params
WHERE params.key = "ga_session_id"
```

in this query, I got 24,473,721 rows in total, which seems to have "ga_session_id"
but, because the `mytable` have 24,753,258 rows, so there are at lease 279,537 rows which have no "ga_session_id".

So i want to know which event_name have no "ga_session_id", and how many of it.

Any possible codes? please help :'(

ADD) 
 Adding '!' to WHERE is not a solution(i've tried)
Because UNNESTing adds an additional rows. it results more than 189 million rows which exceed original table row.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event_name, COUNT(event_name) as count_event_name
FROM
  `mytable`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params
WHERE params.key != "ga_session_id"
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, using UNNEST generates a lot of rows. This is because for each original row (same event_name), you have one row generated per each event_params "subrow".

When you do the unnesting, those 24,753,258 rows are unnested into a lot more (of the order of 200 million).

From those, 24473721 meet the condition params.key = "ga_session_id", and about 189 million don't (that's why they appear in the != clause).

What you have to keep in mind is that for a same event (which is identified with a timestamp and name), when you apply the unnest operator lots of rows are generated, so with your query you are counting each event more than once.

Having said that, if what you want to do is to know how many events contain the "ga_session_id", you should do a query like this

```
 #standardSQL
SELECT
  event_name, COUNT(DISTINCT event_timestamp) as number_of_each_event_name
FROM
  `mytable`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params
WHERE params.key = "ga_session_id"
GROUP BY event_name
```

And if you want to do the contrary, you can apply the != condition

If you want to get the total number of events that meet the condition, without splitting them according to the event_name, your query is this one:

```
     #standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_timestamp) as total_number_of_events
FROM
  `mytable`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS params
WHERE params.key = "ga_session_id"
```

The result of this query, added to the result of the same query with the != condition, should be now  24,753,258, which was the original number of rows (events) you had in your table.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i have additional question about your solution. Does value of 'event_timestamp' unique for each event_name? if it is true, the query seems to be work. But a code below that i wrote to verify whether event_timestamp is unique, shows  it is not unique... Is there any wrong with the code?

#standardSQL
select count(event_name), count(distinct(event_timestamp))
from `analytics_mytable`

Comment: Hi! The event_timestamp is unique for each EVENT, two different events might have the same event_name but they will have different event_timestamp. There is nothing wrong with your code, there might be several events with different timestamps and the same event_name.